# Sharepoint 2013 REST API - Shared Documents / Author Info In one Call?

Tags: 2013, rest, integration

We are in the process of integrating from Sharepoint 2007 to Sharepoint 2013.  We have a java based application using Sharepoint 2007 SOAP based webservices.

In Sharepoint 2013 we are using the REST API.  And I am not seeing an obvious way to make a single call to get a list of documents for Shared Documents and have it include the Author's name.

I am calling to this REST endpoint:

https://www.acme.org/sites/PortalTest/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/PortalTest/Shared%20Documents')/Files?$select=*

I do get an Author property back, but it points to another REST end point (partial JSON response):

```
            "Author":{
           "__deferred":{
              "uri":"https://www.acme.org/sites/PortalTest/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/PortalTest/Shared%20Documents/Test.docx')/Author"
           }
```

Now I could make separate calls to get the Author information, but I'd rather not do it that way.

Is there anyway to make one call to get the documents in a Shared Documents folder that will include the author's name using the Sharepoint 2013 REST API?

EDIT TO ADD:

I found the answer.  Adding the "expand" parameter will flush out deferred properties:

https://www.acme.org/sites/PortalTest/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/PortalTest/Shared%20Documents')/Files?$expand=Author

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
?$select=Author/Id,Author/Name,Author/Title,Editor/Id,Editor/Name,Editor/Title,*&$expand=Author,Editor
```

Answer (score 0):

I was myself looking for an answer to this problem today. But whenever I attempted to add the query parameters to the URL straightaway I got an error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
> client (?)

So those of you that are also bothered by the above error message, you might want to try the following:

Endpoint (taking from the question):
`https://www.acme.org/sites/PortalTest/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(@a1)/Files`

Query parameters (declare them separately):

`@a1`: `"/sites/PortalTest/Shared%20Documents"`
`$expand`:`"Properties,Author,CheckedOutByUser,ModifiedBy"` (Depending on which ones you need. The entire list is available [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn450841(v=office.15)#file-properties))

---

Note:
I am invoking the endpoints from my Java middleware and for that I'm using `Client`, `WebTarget` and `Invocation.Builder` from the `javax.ws.rs.client` namespace.

```
Client client; // Construct your client here with your token, secret and other attributes

WebTarget target = client.target("https://www.acme.org/sites/PortalTest/_api/Web")
.path("/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(@a1)/Files")
.queryParam("@a1", "%27%2Fsites%2Fdms%5Fo2%2FShared%20Documents%27") // encoded!
.queryParam("$expand", "Properties,Author,CheckedOutByUser,ModifiedBy");

Builder request = target.request();

//...
```